# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException on consuming an event payload of generic type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have Spring Boot `3.1.1` kotlin application which is using Spring Cloud `2022.0.4` to consume Kafka events.

consumer function:

```
@Bean
    fun ipConsumer(): Consumer<Message<PayloadWithEmbeddedHeaders<InstructionalPlanCreatedEvent>>> {
        return Consumer {
            
            if (it.headers[PublisherKafka.EVENT_TYPE_HEADER_NAME] == InstructionalPlanCreatedEvent::class.java.simpleName) {
                process(ip = it.payload.body)
            }
        }
    }
```

Genreric type class:

```
data class PayloadWithEmbeddedHeaders<T>(val headers: Map<String, Any> = emptyMap(), val body: T)
```

event class:

```
data class InstructionalPlanCreatedEvent(
    val id: UUID,
    val organisationId: UUID,
    val organisationName: String? = null,
    val curriculumId: Long,
    val curriculumName: String? = null,
    val subjectId: Long,
    val subjectName: String? = null,
    val gradeId: Long,
    val gradeName: String? = null,
    val academicYearId: Long,
    val academicYear: String? = null
)
```

In my consumer function when `it.payload.body` is accessed it throws `ClassCastException` because it is coming as `LinkedHashMap`.

Also, it is not failing in binder test but fails with actual kafka event coming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been addressed with [this commit](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/commit/8e9948c4c3fc18824408c263938e70f8e416545e).

Can you please explicitly add this as a dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```